# Trigger to UPDATE after UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, trigger, update, row-modification-time

I want to make a trigger to record the time of any update as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER col_update
AFTER UPDATE ON col
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE col SET updated=NOW() WHERE id=NEW.id; // or OLD.id
END
```

The problem is that when this trigger tries to update the `updated` column, it is also another update event, which runs the trigger. This will create an infinite loop, which does not work.

How can I store the update time in the corresponding column?

I wish to use a trigger because there are many columns in the table. If I try to set the update time manually, I would need to modify many queries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a `BEFORE` trigger instead, and set the `updated` column assigning a value to `NEW.updated` (this would be a simple assignment, not an `UPDATE`).  This way you won't trigger additional `UPDATE`s.

Your trigger body will simply look like

```
SET NEW.updated = NOW()
```

I usually use `AFTER` triggers only for modifying *other* tables, `BEFORE` for modifying the new (or updated) row, or suppress `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1):

If like in your case, you want to change the updated field every time the record has been changed, you do not need a trigger.

You can use MySQL's automatic initialization/updating like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtabelname` ADD `updated` DATETIME on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Or at the time of table creation, [from the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, **WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
after insert or update
ON [TABLE] FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.proc_name();
```

Comment: `pg_trigger_depth` does not exist in MySql. It is PostreSQL specific